# JNDI lookup failing when looking up JMS queue in WebLogic 10.3.5

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic

I'm new to JMS programming and am running into NameNotFoundException, even though, in looking at the Admin Console, it shows the JNDI name that is failing.

The exception produced is:

**javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'tutorialqueue'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'tutorialqueue'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:252)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:411)**

In the Admin Console, I see:

Name - TutorialJmsConnectionFactory
Type - Connection Factory
JNDI Name - tutorialconnectionfactory  
Subdeployment - Default Targetting 
Targets - AdminServer

Name - TutorialJmsQueue
Type - Queue
JNDI Name - tutorialqueue
 
Subdeployment -
Targets -

The console shows the *tutorialqueue* JNDI name that the exception says it can't find.  Also, the tutorialconnectionfactory name WAS successfully found.  Might it have to do with the Subdeployment and/or Targets being blank?

Here is the code where the lookup occurs/fails:

```
QueueConnectionFactory queueFactory = ( QueueConnectionFactory ) ic.lookup( "tutorialconnectionfactory" );
QueueConnection queueConnection = queueFactory.createQueueConnection();
QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession( false , Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE );
Queue queue = ( Queue ) ic.lookup( "tutorialqueue" );
QueueSender sender = queueSession.createSender( queue );
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In weblogic, you should setup your queue to use the same subdeployment and target(s) as the connection factory, both need to be found in a JVM.  Update your queue's target and subdeployment to match the connection factory and it should start working.

Comment: Thanks John.  That indeed was my problem!

Comment: @Todd Iam facing a similar problem.What are the changes that u made, in order to overcome the problem in the above code or in other settings(like classpath,adding more jars)?

Comment: @Galaxin, the change I made was in WebLogic's admin console when setting up the queue itself.  The settings:

Name - TutorialJmsQueue
Type - Queue
JNDI Name - tutorialqueue
Subdeployment - <blank>
Targets - <blank>    Required that I set the subdeployment and targets fields

Comment: I've created a new question, as my problem is identical, but I cannot get this solution to work. If any of you would like to take a look at it, here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285627/how-can-i-update-my-weblogic-jms-queues-target-and-subdeployment-to-default-and

Answer (score 0):

To add Everything is ok... But you need replace

```
> tutorialconnectionfactory and 
> tutorialqueue
```

with

```
> jms/tutorialconnectionfactory and 
> jms/tutorialqueue
```

then I think it will work fine...