# How can I update my weblogic JMS queue's target and subdeployment to default and AdminServer?

Tags: java, jms, jndi, message-queue, weblogic11g

I have a problem identical to this question:
[JNDI lookup failing when looking up JMS queue in WebLogic 10.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914284/jndi-lookup-failing-when-looking-up-jms-queue-in-weblogic-10-3-5)

However, I can't figure out how to actually implement the solution. It seems simple enough to match the subdeployment and target to the same for both, but it isn't for me:

1. If I change the connectionfactory's subs and target, I get the same error as i used to get on the queue, on the connectionfactory also
2. Default targetting is not an option for queues, only connectionfactories.

So how is it possible to match these settings, and make this work? I am using weblogic 10.3.2

Comment: If the answer is useful please mark as accepted, otherwise post your own answer and mark that as accepted.

Comment: I can actually not remember how this issue got resolved. As no answers were suggested within the first couple of weeks, I restarted the tutorials, and after a few attempts it just worked. I still do not know what the mistake was in the first place. In other words, I have no answer to my question yet. And neither do you, as you are posting a link to a tutorial, and some java code, that is at least semi-off-topic, if you consider the title of my question. In other words, neither my solution or your solution really answers the question.

Comment: Still, thanks for the effort.

Comment: aaaaand, the error is back...